# powershell select-string with recursion to specific file

Tags: windows, powershell, recursion

I'm pretty sure Powershell's select-string will work for me with a bit of Get-ChildItem recursion.

I have many directories like this:

```
abc_123
abc_345
abc_567
abc_890
abc_111
abc_569
```

In each directory, there's a specific file with the same path to each file in each directory:

```
abc_123:\AAA\SDK\Settings\foo.settings.xml
abc_345:\AAA\SDK\Settings\foo.settings.xml
abc_567:\AAA\SDK\Settings\foo.settings.xml
```

And so on.

Within the foo.settings.xml file, I want to search for "BAR." and also one line below it:

```
  <name="BAR.ABB"
            default="1"
```

Problem that I'm having is within the directory that has abc_123,abc_345,abc_567, etc, there's other directories that also contain BAR.*. I don't care about those results.

I'm attempting something like this but it's not working.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.* | Select-String -Pattern "BAR.*" foo.settings.xml | Select-Object -Unique Path
```

Where in my command can I specify I only want to search directories beginning with abc_ and at that specific path?

--- edit ---

The path always begins abc_* and foo.settings.xml always has this path:
`abc_*:\AAA\SDK\Settings\foo.settings.xml`

I tried this:
`Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {"abc_*"} | Select-String –Pattern "BAR.*"`, but this seems to give the same results from above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your line `Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.*` you are specifying that you want all files with any extension, because `*.*` is binding to the `-Filter` parameter.

To get all files *starting* with path abc_* and always with the same relative path you can do something like this: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.FullName -like 'abc_*:\AAA\SDK\Settings\foo.settings.xml'} | Select-String ...`

However, given that each foo.settings.xml file is in the same relative directory, this seems relatively inefficient assuming a large number of sub-directories in each `abc_*` dir. A better solution in this case would be something like:

(where $Path is the root path to the location with all abc_* directories)

`Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter abc_* | Foreach-Object {Select-String -Path "$($_.FullName)\AAA\SDK\Settings\foo.settings.xml" -Pattern "BAR.*"}`

Comment: This will correctly select abc* but it won't look in those directories and find foo.settings.xml. The file foo is three directories beneath abc*.

Comment: I misunderstood then. So, you'll need to further qualify the issue. Does the path always have to _start_ with `abc`, or does it just _contain_ `abc` somewhere in the path name? Either way the answer is to do something like:
`Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {"filter for appropriate paths here"} | Select-String ...`
The only thing that changes is the "filter for appropriate paths here"

Comment: Why not only recursively look through directory structures that match the desired format? Eg `Get-ChildItem -Recurse abc*\AAA\SDK\Settings\*.*`

Comment: The `-Filter` parameter of `Get-ChildItem` is very limited. I'm fairly certain it only works on filenames, not entire paths, making `Where-Object` the way forward.

Comment: @BryanWinstead, Yes, the path will always being abc_* and the path to foo.settings.xml is always the same as well. Edited main question. Can you show an example with this info?

Comment: @RegisteredUser I updated the question with what I think you're looking for. Let me know if there's a further misunderstanding.

Comment: Hi @BryanWinstead, That works great! Thanks for taking the time to update your answer.